# stack build exiting with 'cannot find package' error when external packages are involved

Tags: haskell-stack

I just got started learning Haskell. And I chose to work with it on my PC through stack. First day, I worked with [Chris Allen's tutorial](http://howistart.org/posts/haskell/1/) and got stuck at the `stack build` part of it. The command exited with an error as shown below:

```
C:\Users\USER\haskellProjects\bassbull>stack build
primitive-0.6.2.0: download
integer-logarithms-1.0.2: download
primitive-0.6.2.0: configure
primitive-0.6.2.0: build
integer-logarithms-1.0.2: configure
integer-logarithms-1.0.2: build
primitive-0.6.2.0: copy/register
integer-logarithms-1.0.2: copy/register
Progress: 2/11Running C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\
ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --user --no-user-package-db --package-db C:\sr\snapsho
ts\1602ab97\pkgdb describe --simple-output integer-logarithms --expand-pkgroot e
xited with ExitFailure 1

WARNING: cache is out of date: C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/stack/x86_64
-windows/ghc-8.0.2\lib\package.conf.d\package.cache
ghc will see an old view of this package db. Use 'ghc-pkg recache' to fix.
ghc-pkg.EXE: cannot find package integer-logarithms

Running C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\
ghc-pkg.EXE --user --no-user-package-db --package-db C:\sr\snapshots\1602ab97\pk
gdb describe --simple-output primitive --expand-pkgroot exited with ExitFailure
1

WARNING: cache is out of date: C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/stack/x86_64
-windows/ghc-8.0.2\lib\package.conf.d\package.cache
ghc will see an old view of this package db. Use 'ghc-pkg recache' to fix.
ghc-pkg.EXE: cannot find package primitive

C:\Users\USER\haskellProjects\bassbull>stack exec ghc-pkg recache

C:\Users\USER\haskellProjects\bassbull>stack build
integer-logarithms-1.0.2: configure
integer-logarithms-1.0.2: build
primitive-0.6.2.0: configure
primitive-0.6.2.0: build
integer-logarithms-1.0.2: copy/register
primitive-0.6.2.0: copy/register
Progress: 2/11Running C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\
ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --user --no-user-package-db --package-db C:\sr\snapsho
ts\1602ab97\pkgdb describe --simple-output primitive --expand-pkgroot exited wit
h ExitFailure 1

ghc-pkg.EXE: cannot find package primitive

Running C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\
ghc-pkg.EXE --user --no-user-package-db --package-db C:\sr\snapshots\1602ab97\pk
gdb describe --simple-output integer-logarithms --expand-pkgroot exited with Exi
tFailure 1

ghc-pkg.EXE: cannot find package integer-logarithms

C:\Users\USER\haskellProjects\bassbull>
```

After trying out other tutorials I concluded that this happened only when trying to install external packages and dependencies.

Please I need help getting past this challenge I am facing, as I am very much enthusiastic about learning to code in (and coding in) Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved. Much thanks to [Michael Sloan](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-stack/Zmwz6xSMtyk) on the Haskell-stack google group and [Yuji Yamamoto on](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+YujiYamamoto_igrep) on Google+.

I'll just document what I did here:

- I had felt my antivirus software was messing things up (in retrospect, the signs started showing up weeks back) so I updated it.
- I did a clean uninstall of stack, hunted down its associated files/folders and wiped them off.
- Then I reinstalled stack.
- And started again with the tutorial mentioned in the question (*No, Stack Overflow, I don't have 10 points to spare, thank you!*).
- I made sure to be connected to a steady network while doing `stack setup` for the first time, so that everything got downloaded with ease (the other time, connection timed out endlessly while fetching ghc and msys).
- When that was done, I restarted the shell.
- ... and `stack build` completed successfully.

Now, I don't know exactly what did it for me, but I would love to. If it helps, I was (and I'm still) using stack-1.5.1 on a 64-bit windows7 PC.

Now I don't have to dump haskell for F#.